# Azure Cosmos Db .NET v3 - "The input name 'null' is invalid. Ensure to provide a unique non-empty string less than '1024' characters

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to have my Id auto generated during [CreateItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createitemasync?view=azure-dotnet)

I have the `[JsonProperty("id")]` annotation for the Id. And below is generally my content:

```
{"url":"CustomerId/1/ID/team/21","customerId":"1","projectId":"1","endpointId":"1","id":null,"createdDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","lastModifiedDate":"2021-01-02T22:12:00","token":"hi","newAtt":"Appear?"}
```

It appears that after adding `entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` such that the Id is not null, I am able to insert the item into CosmosDB.
However, previously, I suppose the .NET SDK is able to automatically generate one when the "id" field not provided by the client application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you mentioned, V2 uses `Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` as well. with V3 SDK you need to use extension to create unique Id.
Check this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/815)

> If you are using Guid to generate the id you shouldn't be getting
> collisions. The v2 SDK just uses Guid.NewGuid() to generate the ids.
> You can do something similar in v3 SDK with an extension method.

Comment: How is it possible that we will not be getting collision for using Guid.NewGuid()? Possible to share more on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for cosmosDB v3, I needed:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```